# How can I plot $P(x|y)$ when I have $P(y|x)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

There are Cauchy distributions in a two-class one-dimensional classification
problem as follows:

$$P(x\mid w_i )=\frac{1}{πb}\frac{1}{1+((x-a_i)/b)^2}, i=1,2; a_2>a_1$$

I'm requested to plot $P(w_1 |x)$ and $P(w_2 |x)$ on one axis with $a_1=3, a_2=5$ and $b=1$. (Assuming $P(w_1) = P(w_2)$).

I know that $$P(w_1 | x)=(P(w_1 )P(x│w_1 ))/P(x) $$

But I can't get how I can plot $P(w_i|x)$, however I can plot $P(x|w_i)$ and I get the following pic:

[image]

Did I miss something, or just the plot is the answer?

I get this if in the function I introduce $P(x) = P(x|w_1) + P(x|w_2)$:

[image]

Comment: You can compute the posterior $P(w_1|x)$ explicitly using the formula. Note that in this case $P(x)=(P(x|w_1)+P(x|w_2))/2$ by the law of total probability. Then plot it.

Comment: @ArnabAuddy thanks, but anyway I want a formula to draw the plot, what would be that formula?